# Exporting unshown NSViewController to JPG

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, core-graphics, desktop-application

I am working on an desktop app that generates an image from en NSViewController that is not shown.
The view generated has 3 `NSImageViews` which change the content once created.

I manage to export the `NSViewController's` view to JPG file, but it never renders in the image given to the `NSImageView`, it keeps the image which is set in the nib. Also, if I don't set the background color to the view's layer... I get an empty result.

What am I missing here? I guess I need to update the NSViewController's view... but how can I do that? I do not want to show my NSViewController.

My code:

```
- (IBAction)doExport:(id)sender {
    ExportView *view = [[ExportView alloc] initWithNibName:@"ExportView" bundle:nil];
    [view.pic1 setImage:self.pic1.image];
    [view.pic2 setImage:self.pic2.image];
    [view.pic3 setImage:self.pic3.image];
    [view.icon setImage:self.icon.image];

    // Hardcoding for test
    [view.pic1 setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"iPhone 4-Inch Screenshot 1"]];
    [view.pic1 setNeedsLayout:YES];
    [view.pic1 setNeedsDisplay];
    [view.pic1 updateLayer];

    // Setup the image to render
    NSRect imgRect = view.view.frame;
    NSSize imgSize = imgRect.size;

    NSBitmapImageRep *rep = [[NSBitmapImageRep alloc] initWithBitmapDataPlanes:NULL
                                                                    pixelsWide:imgSize.width
                                                                    pixelsHigh:imgSize.height
                                                                 bitsPerSample:8
                                                               samplesPerPixel:4
                                                                      hasAlpha:YES
                                                                      isPlanar:NO
                                                                colorSpaceName:NSDeviceRGBColorSpace
                                                                  bitmapFormat:NSAlphaFirstBitmapFormat
                                                                   bytesPerRow:0
                                                                  bitsPerPixel:0];

    NSGraphicsContext *g = [NSGraphicsContext graphicsContextWithBitmapImageRep:rep];
    [NSGraphicsContext saveGraphicsState];
    [NSGraphicsContext setCurrentContext:g];

    // Set view background color
    CALayer *viewLayer = [CALayer layer];
    [viewLayer setBackgroundColor:[NSColor clearColor].CGColor];
    [view.view setWantsLayer:YES];
    [view.view setLayer:viewLayer];

    // Render
    CGContextRef zCgContextRef = (CGContextRef) [g graphicsPort];
    [[view.view layer] renderInContext:zCgContextRef];

    // Render pic as well, for test
    [view.pic1.layer renderInContext:zCgContextRef];

    // Get the Data for the image
    NSData *exportedData = [rep representationUsingType:NSJPEGFileType properties:nil];

    // Start the savepanel
    NSSavePanel *savepanel = [NSSavePanel savePanel];
    savepanel.title = @"Save chart";

    [savepanel setAllowedFileTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"jpg"]];

    [savepanel beginSheetModalForWindow:self.window completionHandler:^(NSInteger result)
     {
         if (NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton == result)
         {
             NSURL* fileURL = [savepanel URL];

             if ([fileURL.pathExtension isEqualToString:@""])
                 fileURL = [fileURL URLByAppendingPathExtension:@"jpg"];

             [exportedData writeToURL:fileURL atomically:YES];
         }
     }];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it in a very ugly way. Basically what I do is I add the view to my `contentView` and set `setHidden` to `YES` straight away. This will intialize the view. Now I change the content of my Nib view. 
When its time to render the data to `NSData` I change `setHidden` to `NO`, generate the `NSData` and then remove the view.

The end result *(no beautiful code :( )*:

```
- (IBAction)doExport:(id)sender {
    ExportView *view = [[ExportView alloc] initWithNibName:@"ExportView" bundle:nil];
    [view.view setHidden:YES];
    [self.window.contentView addSubview:view.view];

    [view.pic1 setImage:self.pic1.image];
    [view.pic2 setImage:self.pic2.image];
    [view.pic3 setImage:self.pic3.image];
    [view.icon setImage:self.icon.image];

    // Setup the image to render
    NSRect imgRect = view.view.frame;
    NSSize imgSize = imgRect.size;

    NSBitmapImageRep *rep = [[NSBitmapImageRep alloc] initWithBitmapDataPlanes:NULL
                                                                    pixelsWide:imgSize.width
                                                                    pixelsHigh:imgSize.height
                                                                 bitsPerSample:8
                                                               samplesPerPixel:4
                                                                      hasAlpha:YES
                                                                      isPlanar:NO
                                                                colorSpaceName:NSDeviceRGBColorSpace
                                                                  bitmapFormat:NSAlphaFirstBitmapFormat
                                                                   bytesPerRow:0
                                                                  bitsPerPixel:0];

    NSGraphicsContext *g = [NSGraphicsContext graphicsContextWithBitmapImageRep:rep];
    [NSGraphicsContext saveGraphicsState];
    [NSGraphicsContext setCurrentContext:g];

    // Set view background color
    CALayer *viewLayer = [CALayer layer];
    [viewLayer setBackgroundColor:[NSColor clearColor].CGColor];
    [view.view setWantsLayer:YES];
    [view.view setLayer:viewLayer];

    [view.view setHidden:NO];

    // Render
    CGContextRef zCgContextRef = (CGContextRef) [g graphicsPort];
    [[view.view layer] renderInContext:zCgContextRef];

    [view.view removeFromSuperview];

    // Get the Data for the image
    NSData *exportedData = [rep representationUsingType:NSJPEGFileType properties:nil];

    // Start the savepanel
    NSSavePanel *savepanel = [NSSavePanel savePanel];
    savepanel.title = @"Save chart";

    [savepanel setAllowedFileTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"jpg"]];
    [savepanel setNameFieldStringValue:@"Test"];

    [savepanel beginSheetModalForWindow:self.window completionHandler:^(NSInteger result)
     {
         if (NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton == result)
         {
             NSURL* fileURL = [savepanel URL];

             if ([fileURL.pathExtension isEqualToString:@""])
                 fileURL = [fileURL URLByAppendingPathExtension:@"jpg"];

             [exportedData writeToURL:fileURL atomically:YES];
         }
     }];
}
```

Comment: Nice that you posted back. Thanks. Learnt something.